# How can I style a json from kimono api to look like a list with pictures?

Tags: html, css, json, api

I am trying to figure out how to customize my data from kimono api.  I have made the api and i have all the information, but i don't want to use their kimonoblock, but style a type of dynamic list with images, but to take the information from the api...

Is there any way to do that?

any help would be welcome :)

```
{
  "name": "mysteries",
  "count": 10,
  "frequency": "hourly",
  "version": 8,
  "newdata": false,
  "lastrunstatus": "success",
  "lastsuccess": "Wed Aug 06 2014 04:43:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "nextrun": "Wed Aug 06 2014 05:43:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Ancient king's treasure discovered in China",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270384/ancient-kings-treasure-discovered-in-china"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Ancient Mysteries",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270384"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-5-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270384"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-china-horse_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270384/ancient-kings-treasure-discovered-in-china",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Mystery big cat prowling California streets",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270233/mystery-big-cat-prowling-california-streets"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Cryptozoology",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270233"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-5-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270233"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-lioness_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270233/mystery-big-cat-prowling-california-streets",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Russia's $2.8B moon landing plans revealed",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270350/russias-28b-moon-landing-plans-revealed"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Space & Astronomy",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270350"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-5-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270350"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-moon-base-2_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270350/russias-28b-moon-landing-plans-revealed",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Strong winds reveal new Nazca geoglyphs",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270335/strong-winds-reveal-new-nazca-geoglyphs"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Ancient Mysteries",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270335"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-4-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270335"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-nazca-bird-3_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270335/strong-winds-reveal-new-nazca-geoglyphs",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Scientists invent spray-on solar cells",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270330/scientists-invent-spray-on-solar-cells"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Science & Technology",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270330"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-4-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270330"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-solar-array_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270330/scientists-invent-spray-on-solar-cells",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Boy drains entire pond to find his iPhone",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270277/boy-drains-entire-pond-to-find-his-iphone"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Bizarre",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270277"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-4-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270277"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-pond-fall_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270277/boy-drains-entire-pond-to-find-his-iphone",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Mystery of the 'Ground Zero ship' solved",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270288/mystery-of-the-ground-zero-ship-solved"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Modern Mysteries",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270288"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-3-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270288"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-ground-zero_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270288/mystery-of-the-ground-zero-ship-solved",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Giant 6ft penguins once roamed the Earth",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270281/giant-6ft-penguins-once-roamed-the-earth"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Palaeontology",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270281"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-3-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270281"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-penguins_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270281/giant-6ft-penguins-once-roamed-the-earth",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Crowds gather for annual Nexus conference",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270278/crowds-gather-for-annual-nexus-conference"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: The UFO Phenomenon",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270278"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-3-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270278"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-roswell-aliens_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270278/crowds-gather-for-annual-nexus-conference",
          "alt": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "text": "Dinosaurs shrank for over 50 million years",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270118/dinosaurs-shrank-for-over-50-million-years"
        },
        "category": {
          "text": "Category: Palaeontology",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270118"
        },
        "date": {
          "text": "Posted on 8-2-2014",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=270118"
        },
        "pic1": {
          "text": "",
          "src": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/images/news_small/news-magpie_thumb.jpg",
          "href": "http://www.unexplained-mysteries.com/news/270118/dinosaurs-shrank-for-over-50-million-years",
          "alt": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: So, you know how to get the json to your page, you're asking how to format that json and spit it out as a list in html?  If so, what does your json look like?

Comment: Hi barbara. thanks for getting back to me..... I am trying to paste the json code but I am not able to save it, because it says there are characters that can't be saved or something....

Comment: ok, here is the code, I managed to put it on codepen..
http://codepen.io/shaulhadar/pen/kdero

Answer (score 0):

You have options on how you want to do this.  I like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) for this type of thing.  But, you can also do it with a simple loop building up the html.  http://codepen.io/bhlaird/pen/yecpb.  I used jQuery to set the html, but it's easy enought to do with straight javascript also (see comments).

```
// using mustache templating
var template = '<ul>{{#collection1}}<li><a href="{{pic1.href}}"><img src="{{pic1.src}}">{{title.text}}</a></li>{{/collection1}}</ul>';
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, json.results);
$('#usingMustache').html(rendered);
//document.getElementById('usingMustache').innerHTML =rendered;

// using a simple loop
var results = "<ul>";
for (i=0;i<json.results.collection1.length;i++) {
   results += '<li><a href="' + json.results.collection1[i].pic1.href + '"><img src="' + json.results.collection1[i].pic1.src + '">' + json.results.collection1[i].title.text + '</a></li>';
}
results += "</ul>";
$('#usingLoop').html(results);
//document.getElementById('usingLoop').innerHTML =results;
```

Comment: Hi Barbara, and thanks , that's great :)  I will try to implement it right away!!